# slow results using while loop with mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting terribly slow results from the following code. I've been trying to troubleshoot it for hours but with no results. I've included only the relevant code.

Edit:

I am trying to select an id from a database and then use that id to get all the images associated with it. I am then narrowing that group of images down to one. Once I have that image I am resizing it through an external file.

I've tried removing various parts of the code to identify the problem and it seems as if the slow down is being caused by the second query but I am not sure why. Thanks for your help.

```
$getworks = mysql_query ("SELECT a_id from artists where display_works = '1' and active = '1' order by project_year desc, fullname desc");

while ($getworksrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getworks)){
            $totalimages=1;
            $addstyle = "";
            $id = $getworksrow["a_id"];
            $getimages = mysql_query ("SELECT a_id, image_id from images where a_id = '". $id ."' order by position asc LIMIT 1");
            $getimagesrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getimages);

            foreach ($getimagesrow as $getimagesrows){
                extract($getimagesrow);

                if($totalimages > 1){ $addstyle = 'style="display:none;"'; }
                else {
                $myimagename = "http://artist.com/$a_id/images/$image_id" .  "_large.jpg";
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("$myimagename");
                $myimagename = "http://artist.com/artists/resize.php/$a_id/images/$image_id" . "_large.jpg?resize(157x2000)";

                if($getworksrows["layout"] == "vert"){$pl = "_vertical";}else if($getworksrows["layout"] == "website"){$pl = "-s";}else if($getworksrows["layout"] == "video"){$pl = "_video";}else{$pl = "_horizontal";}
                echo "<li class='thumbnail_container' $addstyle> <a class='thumbnail' href=\"../works$pl.php?a_id=" . $getworksrows["a_id"] . "\"><span><img src=\"$myimagename\" /></span>\n</a></li>\n";
                }

                $totalimages++;
            }

}
```

Comment: It's most likely the `getimagesize` on a remote URL that is slow. There may be no way to speed that up. Are you caching the results somewhere?

Comment: Please be more specific about your question, what you are trying to etc.

Comment: Nested SQL queries are always a big performance overhead, in this case you're issuing 1 + 1 per image queries, when you only need to execute 1 (if you learn about JOINs)

Comment: Could you clarify on this? When you say nested AQL I assume you mean my second query which I've identified as the problem. How would I use a JOIN to improve performance?

Comment: imagine this, for every item you first get (say 1000), you are executing secondary queries per item, another 1000 queries! that's the overhead! as compared to a JOIN, you only have to query once to get both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a a big performance overhead to execute queries like this specially when parent query have large no. of records.

You should use join artists  table with images table and get all data by single query.

Later on make 2D array of per artists  and images. and loop according to 2D array to display data

Below is join query you should use:

```
SELECT * from artists as art 
left join images as img  on art.a_id=img.a_id 
where display_works = '1' and active = '1' 
order by project_year desc, fullname desc
```

In While make data array:

```
   while ($getworksrow = mysql_fetch_object($getworks)){

    $data['a_id']['img_id']=$getworksrow->image;  //Make 2D array
   ........
   ........

    }
```

looping and display data :

```
foreach($data as $id=>$images)
{
   foreach($images as $val){
     // Do your stuff for displaying data
   }

}
```

So please do required changes.

Comment: i suppose this will help if you have "combinations" in effect of the joins http://stackoverflow.com/q/9156109/575527

Comment: Can you more thoroughly explain this? I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: I don't understand line following the while statement. Where did [$artist_id], [$img_is] and $getworksrow->image get defined?

Comment: that is not actual code .It's just format how to make 2D array. Just do something like this with your actual field names. It's not possible to paste whole code here

Comment: Yeah, okay but I don't think your join query is working. I can't get it to return any data.

Comment: I have not tested. As I said you need to required changes. My moto here is that you should use join instead of executing subquery in loop.

Comment: Okay I understand that the query in my loop is causing problems and I appreciate you trying to help. I would like to figure out why the join query does no seem to be doing anything. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: check it once by removing where clause.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is the where clause. But how can I include it?